# How can I integrate shopware with other application?

Tags: shopware

I have an application in `codeigniter`. While purchasing a product from shopware website can I send all the product related information to my application? If yes, how can I implement that?

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question to show, what you have already tried and what is not working. Including source code can also help to unterstand the problem.

Comment: This is definitely possible. Write a Shopware Plugin: [Plugin quick Startup Guide](https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/plugin-quick-start/), subscribe to a desired event: [Event guide](https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/event-guide/) and implement custom logic to send your required order data to your codeigniter application, for example via a REST: [CodeIgniter Rest Server](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver)